# How to put files in flume spooldir one by one?

Tags: hadoop, flume, bigdata

I am using **flume spooldir** to put files in HDFS, but I am getting so many small files in HDFS. I thought of using batch size and roll interval, but I don't want to get dependent on size and interval. So I decided to push files in flume spooldir one at a time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source, if you set `a1.sources.src-1.fileHeader = true`, then you can specify any headers (for example the file name header) in the HDFS Sink (see `%{host}` in the escape sequence description at https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink.

EDIT:
For an example config, you can try the following:

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /flumespool
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeader = true

a1.channels = c1
a1.channels.c1.type = memory

a1.sinks = k1
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /flumeout/%{basename}
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
```

Comment: can you provide any example !

Comment: @animal: I have edited the answer, it includes an example config now

Comment: But in this example you are not using a1.sources.src-1.fileHeader

Comment: If you look at https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source , you see that you have different parameters for different goals. If you need the whole path, you should use fileHeader. If you only need the filename, it's sufficient to use basenameHeader.